# Class not found when unmarshalling finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

I’m getting

> Class not found when unmarshalling:
>   com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams when
>   testing purchases with Static Responses.

My Android version is 4.2.2
My Play Store version is 5.8.8

I’m using a@email1.com as a developer account in play.google.com and using b@email2.com as an account on my android device.

My application id is same on a device com.gomadkids.turmaliworld and in play.google.com

I have installed google play services on my android device yesterday, so it’s the latest

I’m using target-sdk-version="23", but also tried with 16 and 19

I have installed full sdk (API 23) and Google Play Extra services

I have added my device google account to test accounts for license testing list
http://grab.by/JU3I

I’m having apk uploaded to alpha and beta testing, and my device account included into testers http://grab.by/JU4g

so everything looks fine, but when im trying to process “android.test.canceled” purchase im getting -

```
08-26 16:23:33.094: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(488): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!

08-26 16:24:36.282: E/dalvikvm(18831): Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza

08-26 16:25:12.938: E/Parcel(488): Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams, e:   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams

08-26 16:25:14.016: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(488): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
```

but google play small window appears on a transparent background (so i see icons of other apps) with a buy button, and payment successfull. But then it not returns me to application, and looks like application is restarted.